# How to sort one array and use key order to sort a second array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Right now I have two arrays - `$totaltimeplayed` and `$gameslist` where each value in `$totaltimeplayed` refers to time spent playing the corresponding game in `$gameslist`. I want to sort the time spent playing a game in `$totaltimeplayed`, and then accordingly sort the games in `$gameslist`.

My code so far:

```
arsort($totaltimeplayed);
$key_order = array_keys($totaltimeplayed);
$sort_games = array_combine($key_order, $gameslist);
ksort($sort_games);
```

When I use `print_r()`, it seems the sorting of $gameslist is arbitrary and in no particular order.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love [`array_multisort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php):

```
array_multisort($totaltimeplayed, SORT_DESC, $gameslist);
```

Comment: Major ID 10 T error. The PHP.net manual made it seem like arsort() automatically sorted in descending order. Thank you!